# Enabling Offline Sync: Sync works, Offline does not

Tags: c#, azure, uwp, azure-mobile-services

I get below error when attempting to be offline, I began with the starter code as instructed by the Docs and I just keep getting the error.

I followed the details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-windows-store-dotnet-get-started-offline-data

Even trying a new download of the starter code doesn't seem to work, for what ever reason the app refuses to acknowledge that it is offline.  My offline data is synced and is available, but as soon as I am without connectivity the app crashes with the following exception:

> Message:  The text associated with this error code could not be found.
>   The server name or address could not be resolved StackTrace: 
>   {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80072EE7): The text
>   associated with this error code could not be found. The server name or
>   address could not be resolved at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpHandlerToFilter.d__4.MoveNext()
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.d__86.MoveNext()}

The fact that it is even attempting to resolve is puzzling.  What have I not implemented?

I am at a complete loss as to what is causing this and why after having followed the documentation exactly, it does not work.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: In which code line you get this exception?

Comment: When it tries to do the "PushAsync"

**_await App.MobileService.SyncContext.PushAsync(); // offline sync_**

Comment: So as per the documentation _"Notice your sync failed on refresh when the app launched"_ which Is great, but it crashes...

Comment: @sunteen-wu-msft any further thoughts on this?

as a note, I am have implemented authentication as well in the app, not that I would think this should cause an issue seen as I also followed the docs on that